# How can I make seamless virtualization work with virtualbox and rdesktop?

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop

There are lots of tutorials on the web how can this be done. I followed this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SeamlessVirtualization but they all are basically agree on what needs to be done. Howerver, when I run my virtualmachine in headless mode:

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm winxp
```

and try to connect to it with:

```
rdesktop -A -s "c:\Program Files\ThinLinc\WTSTools\seamlessrdpshell.exe notepad.exe" 192.168.123.103:3389 -u user -p password
```

I only get to connect to full windows desktop, not to one application (notepad in this case). I have no idea what is wrong, I only found someone with the same problem here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12404643 (He is on Mint, I am on Ubuntu 12.10).

Comment: What version of **Ubuntu**? *Have you looked at Remmina?* [http://remmina.sourceforge.net/]

Comment: 12.10, added it to the question. Remmina looks just like a frontend, no? I do not think the problem is with the syntax of my command (but I cannot even get reminna to connect as I am able to connect on the command line).

Comment: Hm, so when I in the windows xp guest manually run `Program Files\ThinLinc\WTSTools\seamlessrdpshell.exe notepad.exe`, then close it down and try the rdesktop command once again, it works. Weird.